# POO usando Django

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, django, estilo-de-codificação

Estou começando a trabalhar com Django, mas estou com alguma dúvidas de como organizar meu projeto, gostaria de saber a melhor forma de estruturar meus projetos.

Eu estou estou acostumado com as linguagens em que eu modelo cada entidade com seus atributos e métodos em uma classe que fica em apenas um arquivo, porém em Django o que vejo é que eu apenas tenho uma view que lá dentro eu defino diversas classes. Essa é a forma correta ?

Vi que algumas pessoas criam um App para cada entidade, isso seria o que fica mais próximo do que estou acostumado, mas é uma forma correta ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não, não é a forma correta.

Falando de uma forma simples, o django trabalha com apps. Cada app que você cria em seu sistema, deve seguir o contexto de algo.
Por exemplo:
Se em meu sistema eu tiver os seguintes modelos:

```
Cliente
Produto
CategoriaProduto
Venda
ItensVenda
```

Neste caso, você pode ter 3 apps no sistema:

- Clientes #app clientes

  - Cliente
- Produtos # app produtos

  - Produto
  - CategoriaProduto
- Vendas # app vendas

  - Venda
  - ItensVenda

Você pode pode colocar 50 modelos em uma app da mesma maneira que pode colocar 1 modelo em uma app.
O Two Scoops of Django (livro que fala sobre boas práticas de django), diz que se você tiver mais de 5 models em uma app, você deve dividir sua app em duas.
Se você tiver um modelo bem genérico que pode ser utilizado em vários sistemas, você pode ter uma app só para ele. Isso facilitará muito sua vida.
Por exemplo: "Categoria" é algo que pode ser utilizado em vários sitemas, o que muda é o contexto da categoria. Em um sistema de vendas é categoria de produtos, em um sistema de atendimentos é o tipo do atendimento..

Não é algo que deva a ser levado a risca, mas você tem que ter em mente que cada coisa deve estar no seu lugar. E trabalhar de forma modularizada, significa que cada coisa deve estar no seu devido lugar.
Isso ajudará na refatoração e manutenção do código.

Já tive a infelicidade de trabalhar em códigos que os antigos desenvolvedores criavam uma única app "core" e jogavam todos os models do projeto ali dentro.
Isso é muito ruim porque você tem milhares de coisas armazenadas no mesmo lugar.
Ai para ver algo no projeto, sobe arquivo... desce arquivo.. sobe de novo pra ver se importou algo.

Sobre a questão de view, o django trabalha com a estrutura "MVT", Model, View e Template. Nesse meio tem seus formulários também.

Gosto explicar dessa maneira (de forma bem básica):

- Model: Responsável pelas classes do sistema, as abelas que irão para o banco de dados.
- Forms: Responsável pelo "o que" será apresentado e o como será apresentado (referente aos models).
- View: Responsável por enviar e receber suas requisições.

Não posso dizer que está errado em dizer que tem classes em suas views porque se estiver trabalhando com Class Based View, você terá classes em suas views.
Caso esteja nesse caminho, recomendo seguir inicialmente por Function Based View para depois pular para CBV.

Sobre a arquitetura do projeto em si, você pode organizar dessa forma:

```
project/
    clientes/
        models.py
        views.py
        ...
    produtos/
    project/
        settings.py
        urls.py
        ....
    vendas/
```

Um projeto bem modularizado e boas práticas é incrivelmente mais fácil de ler e entender.
Você deve fazer seu código de maneira que se um outro desenvolvedor trabalhar nele, ele veja que você se importava com a qualidade do código.

Comment: Ótimo, ajudou bastante, obrigado!

Comment: Show! Procura dois livros: Two Scoops of Django e Clen Code.. O Two scoops fala de boas práticas de django e o clean code fala sobre código limpo, como deve ser um código. Os dois lhe tornarão um desenvolvedor muito melhor.